# Compare stored procedure returned dates with console application current date

Tags: c#, xml, stored-procedures, console-application

I have one stored procedure, which displays set of days like below.

```
2015-08-08
2015-08-22
2015-09-05
2015-09-19
2015-10-03
2015-10-17
2015-10-31
2015-11-14
2015-11-28
2015-12-12
2015-12-26
```

I have one XML file in Console application. Which has one root element and one child element. Child element has default value 40. like below,

```
<Hours>
  <TotalHours>40</TotalHours>
</Hours>
```

**Requirement** : **Whenever the current date in console application matches with any one of the stored procedure returned date, it should change the xml value from 40 to 48.**

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, can you clarify what 'Whenever these days come' means?

Comment: After calling this stored procedure, xml element value should change to 48 thats it

Comment: Now edited. I think u can understand my requirement now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    static void Main()
    {
        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;            

        //Mock dataTable is used instead of stored procedure resultset
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
        dt.Rows.Add("2015-08-11");
        dt.Rows.Add("2015-08-13");

        string xmlFile = "hours.xml";            

        var isDateFound = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                          where row.Field<DateTime>("Date") == currentDate
                          select row;
        if (isDateFound.Count() > 0)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(xmlFile);
            var node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("TotalHours");
            node.InnerText = (Convert.ToInt32(node.InnerText) + 8).ToString();
            doc.Save(xmlFile);
        }         

    }
```

--SJ

Answer (score 0):

This works,

```
public class Class1
{
   static void Main()
   {
       SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
       conn.Open();
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("calculatesaturday", conn);


       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstsaturday", SqlDbType.Date).Value = "2015-08-08";
       SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
       DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
       dt1.Load(reader);
       conn.close();
       string xmlFile1 = "xmlfile.xml"; 

       DateTime currentDate1 = DateTime.Now.Date;

       var isDateFound = from row in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                         where row.Field<DateTime>("StartDate") == currentDate1
                         select row;
       if (isDateFound.Count() > 0)
       {
           XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
           doc.Load(xmlFile1);
           var node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("TotalHours");
           node.InnerText = (Convert.ToInt32(node.InnerText) + 8).ToString();
           doc.Save(xmlFile1);
       }       
   }
```

}

Here, "StartDate" is the column name from stored procedure

**Creadits @codeninja**